# Google Maps API v3 are not displaying more than 10 markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using Geocoder callback function for getting latitude and longitude value which is asynchronous.

This works great for the 1st 10 items. I will see a markers on the map as well as those 10 listed on my sidebar. However, the 11th item and beyond will not display anything. I am querying our internal database based on parameters set which often will produce 30+ rows returned in the database table which I am looping through.

Is there any way to display more than 10 addresses on google map. or is there any need to purchase any license for get additional API for geocoder .

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Geocoding services are rate limited and subject to quotas (to prevent abuse), the (paid) [Google Maps API for Business](https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing), does have higher limits.  The usual suggestion is to geocode the loctions offline, store the [coordinates in your database](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_exists), then use those coordinates to display the markers.

If you can't store the locations in your database, you need to check the return value in the geocoder and delay when it returns over query limit errors.  There are examples of doing that both [here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=OVER+QUERY+LIMIT+delay) and in the [Google Maps API v3 group](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/search?hl=en&group=google-maps-js-api-v3&q=OVER+QUERY+LIMIT+delay&qt_g=Search+this+group).

Comment: Thanks for reply.I can't save the coordinates in database because I am using GPS for locate approx 1500 users in google map whose addresses are changing frequently. So I need to call geocoder for locate all the users that will not solve my problem.Please suggest me that without storing coordinates in database how can I do this.